# Semantic tagging

Tags: rdf, semantics, tagging, opendata

I would like to construct a semantic tagging system, and I was wondering if someone has experience with this and could give me some tips where to start.

The idea is that, when a user is describing a concept with the use of tags, those tags do have a semantic underlying structure(RDF) coming from the open data cloud. While the user is typing, tags suggestions are given. Suggestions are coming from for example dbpedia.

I have been looking at solutions like PoolParty, but maybe there are other options. Ideas are welcome, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For an example, the **NCBO bioportal** has created some widgets used to find words/tags that are part of a given ontology:

http://www.bioontology.org/wiki/index.php/NCBO_Widgets

Same idea for Freebase widget:

http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_Suggest

Comment: Thx! This Freebase widget is exactly what I mean. I also see that you can constraining the filter suggestion so I can narrow on my own topic. Do you know anything about a Thesaurus Manager, an alternative which poolpart offers: http://poolparty.biz/try-it/skossy/